# Scid chess can not save

Tags: scid

I try to save color marking, etc. but the program gives error messages.

“The requested function is not supported by this type of database.”

Can I save this? So far it doesn’t save, amd when I save it won’t save markings.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out a few minutes later  
Go to Menu at top “game” then “Save: Add New Game”
Add a new tag or title and will show in game list so you can pick which one you want!
Saves markings and you can edit tags and of file after